# Comments and \require{AMScd}...

Tags: bug, mathjax, comment

When I type the following code in a comment:

```
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X) @>>> \mathcal O_{X,x}\\ 
@AAA @AAA \\ \Gamma(Y,\mathcal O_Y) @>>> \mathcal O_{Y,f(x)}
\end{CD}$$
```

to generate: $$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X) @>>> \mathcal O_{X,x}\\ @AAA @AAA \\ \Gamma(Y,\mathcal O_Y) @>>> \mathcal O_{Y,f(x)}
\end{CD}$$

I end up with a warning box stating: *Only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified.* It seems that it confuses between *@>>>* in the text mode and *@>>>* in the math mode.

This really should be fixed.

Comment: You don't need to require AMScd. It has been enabled globally. The problem is with the comment procedure disallowing multiple `@` symbols unless ` is in the comment. Try that.

Comment: $$\begin{CD}\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X) @>>> \mathcal O_{X,x}\\ @AAA @AAA \\ \Gamma(Y,\mathcal O_Y) @>>> \mathcal O_{Y,f(x)} \end{CD}$$`

Comment: \begin{CD}\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X) @>>> \mathcal O_{X,x}\\ @AAA @AAA \\ \Gamma(Y,\mathcal O_Y) @>>> \mathcal O_{Y,f(x)} \end{CD} ` It works fine:! Thanks Asaf! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree that this is a bug. However:

1. the `AMScd` package has been enabled by default for a long time now. No need to `require` it explicitly.
2. If you have a ` symbol in your comment, then multiple `@` symbols are ignored. It works out just fine, as the comments to your question prove.

   It's not a fix, but it's a temporary workaround.

Comment: You should have escaped the backtick symbol in item 2.

Comment: I tried. It didn't work very well: ```